# The django admin login in is not working and the template is lost

Tags: django

I just get into the Django.
everything works on my local:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0yw1.png)
but after I deploy it on  the on Heroku, the admin login page becomes like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwTlq.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usKiW.png)
and I can not log in ever thought I create the superuser.
here is my setting.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'event.apps.EventConfig',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.sites',

'allauth',
'allauth.account',
'allauth.socialaccount',
'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
#'django.contrib.gis',
]

 MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'meetUpFinder.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS':[os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
     'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
     'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'meetUpFinder.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
'default': {
   'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
   'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR , 'db.sqlite3'),
}

}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
},
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

SITE_ID = 1
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
'google': {
    'SCOPE': [
        'profile',
        'email',
    ],
    'AUTH_PARAMS': {
        'access_type': 'online',
    }
}
}


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR , 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

please help!

Comment: template is not lost :| static files couldn't bee loaded maybe try dajngo-admin [collectstatic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic)

Comment: after tried this command, it gives me an error on the Heroku console: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/static', it is weird